# Getting data in a table with matching IDs to the pivot table in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've got 3 tables, the users table, the image table, and the favorites table which works sort of like a pivot table, as all it has is ID, image_id, and user_id.

In my user model, I have:

```
public function FavoritedByMe() {
    return $this->hasMany('CommendMe\Models\Favorite', 'user_id');
}
```

In my favorites controller, I have:

```
public function getFavorites($username)  {
    $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();    

    return view('user.favorites')
        ->with('user', $user);
}
```

and this works just fine if I want to get the IDs of all the images I've favorited:

```
@foreach ($user->FavoritedByMe as $favorite)
  {{ $favorite->image_id }}
@endforeach
```

However, what I'd really like to be able to return the view with the images themselves. Something like:

```
$favImages = Images::where('id', $user->FavoritedByMe->image_id);

return view('user.favorites')
       ->with('user', $user)
       ->with('favImages', $favImages);
```

Now obviously this won't work, and will return the error:

> ErrorException in FavoritesController.php line 54: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$image_id

but perhaps some kind of Eloquent relationship would? I've tried making those work but they just don't "click" in my head.

How could I make this work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have an error we can deal with?

Comment: edited to show the error the hypothetical code would show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Favorite` model add this relationship:

```
public function image()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('YourImageModel');
}
```

Then you can acces the image like this:

```
@foreach ($user->FavoritedImages as $favorite)
  {{ $favorite->image->yourProperty }}
@endforeach
```

In the laravel's best practices you should call your `FavoritedByMe` relationship `favorites` since it's obviously related to the user.

Comment: I get the error "Trying to get property of non-object" when trying what you gave me. I'll update my post to show what I tried.